# Compress the string file in Android

Tags: android, compression, gzip

I am storing some string values in a file. This file is always been updated. I have to reduce the size of the file.

So the option I tried is using **gzip** and compress the string value and then store it as bytes. But the size is not getting reduced by a huge margin. Is there any alternate way to reduce the size of the file.

The code I am currently using for compressing the string value is as below.

```
public static byte[] compress(String string) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(string.length());
    GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
    gos.write(string.getBytes());
    gos.close();
    byte[] compressed = os.toByteArray();
    os.close();
    return compressed;
}
```

Comment: what do your strings look like and who much do you save at the moment?

Comment: At each moment,  the length of the string will be less than 100 and will be updating every second.

Comment: well, 100B/s is not too much. The problem with small Strings is, that there is only few room for compression. It is in fact possible, that the zipped data is bigger than your original data if it is quite random.

Comment: Yeah! That is what has to be reduced and has to be updated.